# amavis: [virus_name_to_spam_score] is empty when using certain clam database

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, clamav, amavis

I have a weird behavior regarding virus_name_to_spam_score. I’m using 2 custom Clamav DB. Here are the logs when using SaneSecurity where we can see that everything is working fine:

```
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) run_av (ClamAV-clamd) result: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170612T105753-04428-qozS1fmk/parts/p004: Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL FOUND\n
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) run_av (ClamAV-clamd): /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170612T105753-04428-qozS1fmk/parts INFECTED: Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) lookup_re("Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL") matches key "(?^:^Sanesecurity\\.TestSig_)", result=undef
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) lookup [virus_name_to_spam_score] => undef, "Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL" does not match
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) virus_scan: (Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL), detected by 1 scanners: ClamAV-clamd
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) lookup_re("Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL") matches key "(?^:.*)", result="1"
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) lookup [viruses_that_fake_sender] => true,  "Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL" matches, result="1", matching_key="(?^:.*)"
Jun 12 10:57:53 prd-mail-1 amavis[4428]: (04428-01) Virus Sanesecurity.TestSig_Type4_Hdr.2.UNOFFICIAL matches (?^:.*), sender addr ignored
```

Now when using SecurityInfo.com I can see that the first run the virus is detected but then the virus_name_to_spam_score is empty. What I’m trying to do is use @virus_name_to_spam_score_maps to set the emails coming from this list be marked as spam but since the check is empty unfed is returned and they are always marked as viruses. Here are the logs:

```
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) prolong_timer run_av_3: timer 288, was 288, deadline in 479.8 s
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) run_av (ClamAV-clamd) result: /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170612T092354-18890-TNOnpS50/parts/p013: SecuriteInfo.com.Spam-4703.UNOFFICIAL FOUND\n/var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170612T092354-18890-TNOnpS50/parts/p009: SecuriteInfo.com.Spam-4703.UNOFFICIAL FOUND\n
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) run_av (ClamAV-clamd): /var/lib/amavis/tmp/amavis-20170612T092354-18890-TNOnpS50/parts INFECTED:
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) lookup_re(""), no matches
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) lookup [virus_name_to_spam_score] => undef, "" does not match
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) virus_scan: (), detected by 1 scanners: ClamAV-clamd
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) lookup_re("") matches key "(?^:.*)", result="1"
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) lookup [viruses_that_fake_sender] => true,  "" matches, result="1", matching_key="(?^:.*)"
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) Virus  matches (?^:.*), sender addr ignored
Jun 12 09:25:32 prd-mail-1 amavis[18890]: (18890-02) lookup_sql_field(virus_lover) rec=0, "email@domain.com" result: undef
```

Any idea what might cause this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. It seems the clamav scanner that was being used did not return the correct value therefore I had to change **@av_scanners** in **/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user** to the following:

```
@av_scanners = (
    #### http://www.clamav.net/
    ['ClamAV-clamd',
    \&ask_daemon, ["CONTSCAN {}\n", "/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl"],
    qr/\bOK$/m, qr/\bFOUND$/m,
    qr/^.*?: (?!Infected Archive)(.*) FOUND$/m ],
);
```

and restart amavis